# django orm, custom method on top of a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

lets suppose that some code in my view looks like this:

```
bar = Bar.objects.get(pk=1)
foos = bar.foo_set.filter(VERY_LONG_COMPLEX_FILTERING_LOGIC)
```

I would obviously want to clean the filter method a bit, by creating a custom method that does the same thing, like so:

```
bar = Bar.objects.get(pk=1)
foos = bar.foo_set.complexfilter()
```

Moving the custom method somewhere to a class would be perfect, but so far I couldn't find any mention of anything like that in the docs. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Placing it in `bar`'s method seems good.

Comment: ok, so I guess it would need include the foo_set call as well?: def complexfilter(self): return self.foo_set.filter(); bar.complexfilter(). So its not possible to do anything custom on top of the foo_set property?

Comment: @murmun I don't think it's possible, but do you really need it? Alternatively you can create cusom manager for `Foo` model and pass `bar` to it as a parameter.